# How to reduce the duplicated codes?

Tags: python, logging

I have to print the thread name , but I need to add function call everywhere:

```
self.logger.debug("{} log".format(currentThread().getName()))
self.logger.error("{} log".format(currentThread().getName()))
```

I use the logging module, is it possible to add a log prefix which comes from a function call?

Antoher case is that the logger is not from logging module, is it possbile to monkey-patch the function, generating some functions so that I can call it like this:

```
self.logger.my_debug("log")
self.logger.my_error("log")
```

I do not want to write many functions manually with duplicated codes for different logging levels, it should be good if the codes are like this

```
for log_level in ("error", "warn", "debug", "info")
...generating functions...
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

Your code could look like this:

```
FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)s %(funcName)-8s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
logger.warning("message here)
```

To stress a point: Logging is normally configured globally. Especially thinks like "what format has the log" and "where does it get logged?" are decided there.
While I dislike the python logging system b/C it'S rather convuluted, I would say that understanding how it works is imperative if you want to log effectively.